# I want to create a reminder of records in asp of before 4 months from today's date in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written this query :

```
SELECT 
    MemberId
    ,Title
    ,LastName
    ,FirstName
    ,MiddleName
    ,Occupation
    ,Productof
    ,Dateofpurchase
    ,Dateofservice
    ,Address
    ,City
    ,Pin
    ,Phone
    ,MobileNo1
    ,Email
FROM
    tbmMember
WHERE 
    Dateofservice <= DATEADD(MONTH, - 4, GETDATE())
```

but this query returning all the records of before 4 months.

Comment: If I got you correctly you want to get all the records whose DateofService is four months before and older? e.g. if today is 3rd August then you want all records whose DateofService was on 3rd April or before. Is that correct? It seems your question title and description are contradictory somehow.

Comment: No,I just wanted only the records of 3rd April if today's date is 3rd August.I got the solution.Only the updations is in   WHERE Dateofservice = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,-4,GETDATE())) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it return before 4 month data from today

```
WHERE Dateofservice >= DATEADD(MONTH,-4,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is time (hours, minute,...) sensitive:

```
SELECT MemberId,Title,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,Occupation,Productof,Dateofpurchase,Dateofservice,Address,City,Pin,Phone,MobileNo1,Email 
FROM tbmMember 
WHERE Dateofservice >= DATEADD(MONTH,-4,GETDATE())
AND Dateofservice <= GETDATE()
```

This one is not time sensitive:

```
SELECT MemberId,Title,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,Occupation,Productof,Dateofpurchase,Dateofservice,Address,City,Pin,Phone,MobileNo1,Email 
FROM tbmMember 
WHERE Dateofservice >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,-4,GETDATE()))
AND Dateofservice <= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

Assuming Dateofservice is date type.

------------- EDIT -----------------

If you just needs the data of 4 months back:

```
SELECT MemberId,Title,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,Occupation,Productof,Dateofpurchase,Dateofservice,Address,City,Pin,Phone,MobileNo1,Email 
FROM tbmMember 
WHERE Dateofservice = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH,-4,GETDATE()))
```

Note that `DateofService` must be date type, otherwise you need to convert that as date by `CONVERT(date, Dateofservice)` as well

Comment: Thanks.This is working.but it returning whole records of before 4 months.and I just want todays day's  record of exactly before 4 month of today's date.    Eg:  if todays date is 3 aug 2016 then i want record of 3rd april 2016 only.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to compare the date of your records with a date four months back from today's date then here is how you can achieve it:

```
SELECT 
    MemberId
    ,Title
    ,LastName
    ,FirstName
    ,MiddleName
    ,Occupation
    ,Productof
    ,Dateofpurchase
    ,Dateofservice
    ,Address
    ,City
    ,Pin
    ,Phone
    ,MobileNo1
    ,Email
FROM
    tbmMember
WHERE 
    CONVERT(Date,Dateofservice) = CONVERT(Date, DATEADD(MONTH, - 4, GETDATE()))
```